# MovieClip button In Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Tried this,

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class test extends MovieClip {
        public function test() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, registerBtn);
        }

        private function registerBtn(e:Event):void {
            this.parent["Homebtn"].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myButtonClick);
        }

        private function myButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("CLICKED");
        }
    }
}
```

[Image](http://i42.tinypic.com/mhpzd4.png)

And the same code on frame 1, And there's a MovieClip Button on stage having Instance name "Homebtn".

Comment: Try to import `flash.events` instead of `flash.event`

Comment: Still, the same problem.

Comment: @Atriace
Tried debugging, but was unable to resolve it. Sorry for disappointing you, but please help.

Answer (score 2):

### Imports

```
import flash.events.*;
```

Importing all classes from a package that originates in `flash` has zero impact on compile size because they're already present in the Flash Player runtime environment.  It's pure monotony that you're required to explicitly declare these imports, but good practice when dealing with third party packages.

### Stage Relationship

Document code (i.e., code in the Flash IDE timelines) have a direct relationship to `MainTimeline`, whereas class files do not.  If you want to add `button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myButtonClick);` to your class, you're not going to be able to do so unless you:

**A:** Pass a pointer to the button/stage/root to the class when instantiating your `test` class:

```
var myObj:test = new test(root)
```

**B:** Wait to add the event listener until after you've given the `test` object a parent relationship to the stage from which to traverse to the button:

```
addChild(test);
```

*inside your class...*

```
public function test() {
    // constructor code
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, registerBtn)
}

private function registerBtn():void {
    this.parent.button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myButtonClick);
}
```

---

### Turn on Debugging

To find the cause of your bugs, you need to debug your code.  If you're using Flash IDE CS6, then you can enable this by going to your publish settings and enabling "Permit Debugging".  This will take your ambiguous error...

```
null object reference at myDocument/doSomething()
```

...to a much clearer...

```
null object reference at myDocument/doSomething() package\myClass.as:20
```

...which now denotes which line in your code to look for your issue.

[image]

### Use the Debug Console

Use the debugging compile mode to bring up the Debug Console.  This will provide you with an immediate look at the line of code in question, as well as the Call Stack, and the state of all available Variables.  No programmer should be without it.

Run by going to the menu "Debug > Debug Movie > Debug", or use the keyboard combo <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

[image]

---

Now that you're armed with the know-how to do this on your own, I'll cover what you'd encounter, and how you'd fix it (since you're new).

First, it's `flash.events` with an "s". So we'll change that.

Next, compiling it we get the following errors:

[image]

So we see on line 7 of our `test.as` class: you've placed the timeline code into the class.

```
var myObj:test = new test(root);
addChild(test);
```

You don't want to instantiate you class from within itself as it'll never get instantiated.  Think of your code as a railroad.  The train starts with your timeline code, and only runs on the rails set before it.  Your class is floating off to the side, ready with all its interesting turns and zigzags, but you have to add it to the rails for it to be actually run.  That's instantiation; we're copying that path onto the current track, and the train runs on it.

So, we get rid of lines 6 & 7, and we're left with `Access of possibly undefined property Homebtn`.  Calling [`this.parent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#parent) is actually a [getter function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000171.html), and it returns a `DisplayObjectContainer`. Because AS3 is a [strongly datatyped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing) language, the compiler will know that there is no such property "Homebtn" on DisplayObjectContainers (silly compiler).  But of course, you know it's there (or at least it will be by the time this code runs).  A simple way of getting around that is by making it evaluate the reference at run-time.

```
this.parent["Homebtn"].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myButtonClick);
```

By encapsulating the button name as a string and within brackets, we've done that.

Now we recompile again, and get the following:

[image]

This is because all [event listeners](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e54.html) receive one argument: an event object.  You may not use it, but not having a variable to hold it is a *no-no*.

```
private function registerBtn(e:Event):void {
```

As a final point. All class functions need to be denoted as to what [namespace](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/namespaces.html) they exist in.  `myButtonClick` needs one, so we'll add it as `private` since no external (ie., non-class based) functions need access to it.

Here's your revised code:

### test.as

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class test extends MovieClip {
        public function test() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, registerBtn);
        }

        private function registerBtn(e:Event):void {
            this.parent["Homebtn"].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myButtonClick);
        }

        private function myButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("CLICKED");
        }
    }
}
```

### test.fla (timeline code on frame 1)

```
import test;

var Homebtn:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
Homebtn.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
Homebtn.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 150, 25);
Homebtn.graphics.endFill();
addChild(Homebtn);

var testObj:test = new test();
addChild(testObj);
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, I must appreciate your work & patience. What I'm going to ask next gonna disappoint you. But I need to, I created the AS with the same code that you provided just to test and understand it. And added the code(that you mentioned) also on the first frame. There's a Movieclip button on stage with an Instance name Homebtn. But I'm getting error

Comment: The `test.fla` code I gave you creates a movieclip `Homebtn`, which I used to test the code with.  You've added your own `Homebtn` but yours is a `Button`  object, instead of a `MovieClip` which is why it's producing an error. If you get rid of lines 3 thru 7, I suspect the issue will be resolved.  Alternatively, don't create a button with the name `Homebtn` if you're going to use those lines I supplied.